# * symbol in C pointers

Tags: c, pointers, syntax

Here, I've provided a simple code that uses a pointer.

```
void rets(int *px, int *py)
{
    *px = 3;
    *py = 5;
}
int main()
{
    int x, y;

    rets(&x, &y);
    printf("First is %d, second is %d", x, y);
}
```

I just want it to be cleared... In the declaration: `int *px, *py;`, sets aside two bytes in which to store the address of an integer variable and gives this storage space the name **px**. It also sets aside another two bytes in which to store the address of another integer variable and gives this space the name **py**. The asterisks tell the compiler that these variables will contain **addresses** and *not* **values** (*if I'm not mistaken*?), and the int tells it that the addresses will point to integer variables. But — and herein lies the source of much confusion:

```
*px = 3;
*py = 5;
```

it's used in a slightly different way here than it is in pointer declarations. What does it mean?

Comment: Why the vote to close? It's a perfectly reasonable question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So in the function declaration, you are declaring pointers to int that will be passed as parameters. In the definition you are **dereferencing** the pointers so actually using the variables space declared in main. If you didn't dereference, you would just be changing the pointer not what is pointed at. Where you call rets(), you are giving the address of the variables defined in main using &.

Comment: what is the advantage of putting `void` in `main()`?

Comment: none, should be int along with a couple of parameters for argc and argv. It was just a quick edit to clarify the question.

Answer (score 4):

```
*px = 3;
*py = 5;
```

It means that you give the value `3` to the memory pointed by the pointer `px` and you give the value `5` to the memory pointed by the pointer `py`.

Comment: so you mean: the function has *indirectly* passed the value 3 and 5 to the variables **x** and **y**?

Comment: @aerohn you have given the function the addresses to x and y, and this allows the function to change the values of x and y by accessing the addresses (dereferencing). In C a function gets a copy of the argument. So of you want a function to change variables you give it a pointer to that variable.

Answer (score 1):

basically, '*' is used in 3 different ways in C(unless I missed something), depending on the context

1. multiplication
2. declaring pointer variables
3. dereferencing

let's ignore #1.

when you have something like

```
TYPE * x;
```

this declares a variable x which holds a pointer to a value of type TYPE.

whereas when you have

```
*x
```

with x being a pointer, this refers to what x is pointing to, which is known as dereferencing(since pointers are also known as references)